# Copy value AND row number to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've got code that looks for a text string and will copy the whole cell contents of each instance it finds in to a column on another sheet.
The original data can contain duplicates though, so I'd like to add in the row number in the column next to where I'm pasting the cell values.

Is this possible?

In the example below, it searches for any cell containing "AIN:" in column A of worksheet "source code" and copies it to the next empty cell in column A of sheet "AIN".
Would love to be able to add the row number of the value being copied in to column B of sheet "AIN"

Regards,
Adam

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim lastRow As String
Set SrchRng = Worksheets("Source Code").Range("A:A")

Sheets("Source Code").Select
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "AIN:") > 0 Then
        cel.Copy
        lastRow = Worksheets("AIN").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("AIN").Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next cel
```

Have searched on here but couldn't find a similar problem. Found out how to grab the row number from google but so far tried the below and it's getting stuck...
("invalid qualifier" on the rownum.Copy line)

```
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "AIN:") > 0 Then
        cel.Copy
        rownum = cel.Row
        lastRow = Worksheets("AIN").Cells(Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("AIN").Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        rownum.Copy
        Worksheets("AIN").Range("B" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next cel
```

Comment: `Worksheets("AIN").Range("B" & lastRow).value=rownum` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure that's possible.
Some remarks & improvements to your code:

- If you only want to copy the content of cells, use the `Value`-property. Don't use Copy&Paste, this will slow down your code.
- No need to use `select` on the worksheet. The Range (`SrchRng`) knows already on which sheet you want to work.
- Declare `lastRow` as number (`Long`, don't use `Integer`).
- You need to find the last row in use of you destination sheet only once, after that, simply increase the value of `lastRow` by one.
- To access a cell next (or below, or above, you get the idea) to another, use the function `Offset`, eg `Range("A" & lastRow).Offset(0, 1)` (offset 0 rows and 1 column).
- I am using the `With`-clause to access the destination sheet, this saves from repeatedly specify `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AIN")`. Note the dots in front of `.Cells` and `.Range`.
- You are looping over all cells of column A (> 2million) which will take quite a long time. You should limit this to the cells that are really used. There are several ways to do so (eg figure out the last row similar to how you do it for the destination sheet). I show a different way using `Intersect`.
- An alternative to looping over all cells of col A would be to use `Find` and loop over the result or to set an AutoFilter and loop over the visible cells.

Your code could look like that:

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source Code").Range("A:A"), _
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source Code").UsedRange)

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AIN")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(cel.Value, "AIN:") > 0 Then
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            .Range("A" & lastRow).Value = cel.Value
            .Range("A" & lastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = cel.row
        End If
    Next cel
End With
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the swift reply!

I've tried it just now and it's kind of worked: In the sheet AIN it's put the row number in B2 relating to the value in A2, however it's putting the same number in B3, B4, B5, etc, all relating to the row of the value in cell A2. Hope that made sense!

It's somehow not updating the cel.row value each time. Any ideas please?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce that behavior. `cel.Row` is always the row number of `cel`, and as you iterate over your search range, it changes with every iteration. Have you tried to execute the code step by step using the debugger?

Comment: Hi FunThomas,
Many appologies, small typo on my behalf. After this code is run I'm copying down other formula I have on the AIN sheet, and originally I was copying down from B2 to J2, which was over-writing the row numbers, copying down the first one!

Thanks again for all your assistance!